# React-Native WebView doesn't update after going away and back to the WebView

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-webview

I use `react-native-navigation` with community `web-view` component.

My problem is - the screen is called WebLinkScreen and it opens different weblinks inside my app.

If I go away from that screen with let's say opened `https://example.com`. Then open a different page that passes an argument with URL `https://sample.com`, I still see example page being opened.

What am I doing wrong? Who is caching the screen/page? Is it a WebView component or `react-native-navigation` stackNavigator?

Comment: Can I see the code where the error occurs?

Comment: How did you resolved this issue @Andrei  then ?  I am also facing similar issue.

Comment: @ParvindraSingh I haven't but please do let me know if you figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, for now i had created the pages in mobile side in the last :-(